# Looking for a board-to-board SMD connector found in Google Pixel XL phone

Tags: connector, identification

I am looking a particular connector found in a Google Pixel XL, searched for days without luck. It looks like a Mezzanine Connector but different.

I took some measurement on it and took some pictures:

```
Plug: 1mm × 5mm; pitch size 0.35-0.4mm 
Receptacle: 3mm × 6mm; pitch size 0.35-0.4mm
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is 0.30 mm, and not 0.35 mm?

Comment: i think you are right is definitely not 0.3mm, is somewhere  0.35-0.4mm, difficult to get the right measurement

Comment: For those who wonder what board is that please check [Pixel XL teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Google+Pixel+XL+Teardown/71237), at step 7

Answer (score 0):

How about a Plateau connector from Panasonic?

https://www.yoycart.com/Product/45271541068/

[image]

From this family.

Smallest Mezzanine connectors commercially that I found were 0.4mm and 0.35mm so Google may have negotiated a custom part from Hirose , Panasonic or a number of other reputable OEM's.

If you only need 1 , go look for a phone repair shop or wait 5 years for it to be commercially avail.