# Can't find socket for the Google Pixel 3 XL Pressure Sensor/Strain Gauge

Tags: sensor, socket, header

For the past 4 days, I've been trying to locate this socket, but I'm really struggling. This is now my 3rd attempt at getting help, so I would really appreciate someone more technical, that could help locate/identify it. I've tried searching for the numbers/logos, but can't seem to find anything with google/bing.

The information on the front of the sensor reads: "PT052-N-C4-V1 (IDT?) MK 1820 20180227 142", & the back reads: "PT052-N-S8_V1 180228 (IDT?) 1820 MK".

The closest thing I could find on this topic was another question on StackExchange located [here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/332612/looking-for-a-board-to-board-smd-connector-found-in-google-pixel-xl-phone) That lead me down a deeper hole, & I think I may be really close, but I'm not sure. These are the two products I've found that look like they would work. [AXT514124 | F4S(0.4mm pitch)](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e/search_num/index.jsp?c=detail&part_no=AXT514124&large_g_cd=1&medium_g_cd=12&small_g_cd=122&series_cd=1287) & [Molex 5024261430](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/5024261430/WM9059DKR-ND/3197711)

The Header has two rows of 7 pins each, for a total of 14 pins. The pin pitch is 0.35mm-0.4mm. I'm fairly confident that it's 0.4mm, but I would like to find both a 0.35mm & a 0.4mm connector, just to make sure one of them works.

[This is the part from iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Android/Google-Pixel-3-XL-Left-Edge-Pressure-Sensor/IF356-131?o=1) It's a Google Pixel 3 XL Left Pressure Sensor. [image]

This is a closeup of the header with a little more information on it. It looks like it says "1b" & "H?5". Not sure if that info is relevant. [image]

This photo is the dimensions of the header. The whole size is 4.75mm x 1.25mm. The negative space inside the header measures in at 3.35mm x 0.8mm. [image]

So after it being pointed out (Thanks, brhans & Dave Tweed) that this is a Hirose header, I've been looking at their lineup & nothing really seems to be matching up all the way. The BM23PF is closest header I could find that somewhat matches my dimensions. I strongly believe this has to be a 0.4mm pin spacing.

This is the BM23PF overplayed onto my header.
[image]

Comment: The left marking is a stylized "HRS" for [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/?lang=en#)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a [Hirose BM23PF](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=CL0480-0366-0-51&productname=BM23PF0.8-14DP-0.35V(51)&series=BM23PF&documenttype=2DDrawing&lang=en&documentid=D162585_en) to me.
[image]
[image]
The shape of the metal bits on the ends appears to match closely with your photo and the dimensions look fairly close to what you've measured.
[Digikey link](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-arrays-edge-type-mezzanine-board-to-board/308?k=bm23&k=&pkeyword=bm23&sv=0&sf=0&FV=-1%7C26%2C-8%7C308%2C88%7C92592&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25)

Comment: Brhans, I added an edit to my original post, detailing the BM23PF.

Answer (score 0):

Since that looks a lot like the Hirose logo, I checked their website and quickly found the [BM46 series](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/BM46?lang=en) connectors, which seem to match your photo and description fairly closely. It's possible that you're looking at a custom variation of this standard part.

[image: Hirose BM46]

Comment: Dave, I appreciate being pointed in the right direction, but these seem to have come out after the Google Pixel 3. They were announced at CES in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Molex also has a line called SlimStack for board to board connectors.

Comment: I've already looked at molex yesterday, but I went through all of them & downloaded the 3D models of each socket/header that had 14 pins & compared to my model. Unfortunately they don't seem like they would match up.